# Deletion of Partitions

Tags: hive, hive-partitions, hiveddl

I am not able to drop partition in hive table.

```
ALTER TABLE db.table drop if exists partition(dt="****-**-**/id=**********");
OK
Time taken: 0.564 seconds
```

But partitions are not getting deleted

Below is the what I get when I check partitions of my table:

```
hive> show partitions db.table;
OK
dt=****-**-**/id=**********
dt=****-**-**/id=**********
dt=****-**-**/id=**********
dt=****-**-**/id=**********
```

After running Alter table db.table drop if exists command it should actually delete the partition . But it is not happening so .

Can you please suggest me on this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE db.table drop if exists partition(dt='****-**-**', id='**********');
```

Answer (score 1):

As @leftjoin also mentioned, you have to specify partitions with comma seperated.

```
ALTER TABLE page_view DROP if exists PARTITION (dt='****-**-**', id='**********');
```

Please note -

> In Hive 0.7.0 or later, DROP returns an error if the partition doesn't
>   exist, unless IF EXISTS is specified or the configuration variable
>   hive.exec.drop.ignorenonexistent is set to true.

Due to this reason, your query didn't fail and returned OK response.